# PDO foreach loop doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I am new to PDO and I could not find the answer to the problem I am dealing with here.
I was able to run a `foreach` loop on a table with no `WHERE` clause, but when I replicate it on a similar table *with* a `WHERE` clause, it returns no data!

Here is the code that does not work. I even tried to run it without `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` parameters, still with no luck! Please guide.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="teachers_profile_table table table-bordered">
         <thead>
             <th style="width:20%">Student</th>
             <th>Comment</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
<?php
$pdo = Database::connect();
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_st_comments_abt_tut WHERE tut_id=?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($teacher_id));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($pdo2->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['st_name'].$row['input_date'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['st_comment'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
Database::disconnect();
?>
         </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the db table:
table name: tbl_st_comments_abt_tut
id
tut_id
st_id
st_name
st_comment
input_date
(I have manually entered 3 rows into the table for testing purposes).

Comment: where did you close the first php tag? why are you opening a second one?

Comment: [Getting data out of statement. foreach()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach). you have to iterate over $q variable. while $pdo2 is just a noncence

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile does it matter?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I get an error on my side with that second opening of php tag

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile if you have a problem with basic PHP you have to ask a question of your own.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I will when I encounter that problem.

Comment: I took care of one unclosed php tag prior to the given code above. pdo2 within foreach statement was a typo in which I fixed it. I'll see if I can get it to work using answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve with this line : `foreach ($pdo2->query($sql) as $row)` I'm not even sure if its legal, where does the $pdo2 coming from?

If you follow at Your Common Sense's blog post you will see that your foreach is somewhere in correct, also its important to check if you get results before displaying them.

Your code should look like :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="teachers_profile_table table table-bordered">
              <thead>
              <th style="width:20%">Student</th>
              <th>Comment</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
<?php
$pdo = Database::connect();


$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_st_comments_abt_tut WHERE tut_id= ? ";
$q   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute([$teacher_id]);
$data = $q->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($data) > 0) {

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['st_name'] . $row['input_date'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['st_comment'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
} else {

    echo "no results";
}

Database::disconnect();
?>
                </tbody>
         </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you edit your question with your table structure, so I can see how your data looks like @Ali